# Authentication against N databases using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Using Spring Security, is possible implement a webservice authentication system against N databases? The aim is pass an user, a password and a database name and then do the validation against the target database.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a custom authentication, you need to use an **Authentication Provider**. Here there is an example

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you're trying to achieve, it can be done.

You will need to work on a custom implementation of [AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html). If you make it a @Component you should be able to inject connectors to your different databases. Depending on your overall architecture and design you might want to go with different implementations of this provider for each database. Then you could use database specific implementations of [Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) and rely on the `boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)` method in AuthenticationProvider to route authentication requests properly.